# How to detect changes in value of multiple custom components using a directive on them

Tags: angular

I have multiple **Custom Components** which I wrote myself and now I put a **directive** on them which I want to be able to **detect value changes** of the host component in that directive. I found a solution which was to put a **@HostListener** that wait for change events that raise by value change. but the problem is I have multiple components and then I should use multiple **@HostListener** for different events. How can I have a single generic event which will be triggered by value change on all of my custom components.

```
@HostListener('When_ComponentA_ValueChanged')
@HostListener('When_ComponentB_ValueChanged')
@HostListener('When_ComponentC_ValueChanged')
@HostListener('When_ComponentD_ValueChanged')
@HostListener('When_ComponentE_ValueChanged')
//the list can goes on and on ...
DoSomething()
{
    //
}
```

Comment: show some code that you tried

Comment: Use an eventEmitter that get subscribed in each component you want. You can also replace the eventEmitter with a Subject to achieve that.

Comment: @sadra seyfi create a `@Output` eventEmitter in custom component and emit the event from component and catch that emitter event in directive.

Comment: @NRaghavendra you mean an @ output eventEmitter with one name  on all components that will be triggered on value change?

Comment: @sadra seyfi, Yes that would help you to normailize the event or else you can also use conditional trigger based on component(if used different names in different components) but its better to use a common name.

Comment: thanks @NRaghavendra